# Smallest path in graph theory (network analysis)

Tags: graph-theory, network

This is the scenario:
There is an undirected graph with n nodes and e edges, all nodes are connected.

The question in the scenario:
Every node can be considered as a person in a social network that shares or reads a content. It means that if A is connected to B, C and D, if A shares a content with the network, it will reach directly BCD. It means that to reach all the nodes in the network, it's just necessary that they are adjacent to a node which shared the content.

Q1: is there a way to find the best starting point to reach the entire network?
Q2: is there a way to find a smallest path from that point?

I've already looked at salesman problem and prim'algorithm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to find the [Jordan center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) of a graph. That is, the node(s) which have the minimum eccentricity.

One way to calculate this is to run an all-pairs shortest path algorithm on the graph and see which node has the minimum maximum shortest path.

Comment: Can you suggest how to find using mathematical models/algorithms the Jordan point? I should know how to continue then..

Comment: @NicolaG, run breadth-first search (BFS) from each node v. The number of edges it took to get from v to the last node encountered in a BFS is the eccentricity of v. Once this is completed for all nodes, any node belonging to the set of all nodes with minimum eccentricity represents a good starting point to reach the entire network.